# Flutter seems to skip the FutureBuilder() method

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm not able to read data from Firebase Firestore.

Flutter seems to skip the 'future builder' method.
I'm not getting any error messages, it just seems like Flutter is skipping the code for `FutureBuilder()` method

```dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:doctor_app/data/data.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DatabaseManager {

  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  CollectionReference users = 
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  
  // here method GetUserData is called from another file
  Future<void> GetUserData() async {
    var documentId = user!.email;
    print("in getuserdata");
    FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: users.doc(documentId).get(),
      builder:
      (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
        print("in builder");
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          print("Something went wrong");
        }

        if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
          print("Document does not exist");
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          print("in connection");
          Map<String, dynamic> data =
              snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          fullname = data['FullName'];
          gender = data['Gender'];
          dob = data['Dob'];
          number = data['Number'];
        }

        return Text("loading");
      },
    );
    print("at connection end");
  }
```

Comment: Restarted application in 1,634ms.

I/DynamiteModule( 7360): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 7360): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/flutter ( 7360): in getuserdata
I/flutter ( 7360): at connection end
I/flutter ( 7360): in profilepage

Comment: would you where are you calling this function?